# Adding Firewall rules with ip addresses for PAAS servers using Powershell

Tags: sql, azure

I have Azure environment and I have to add firewall rule into all Pass servers for different subscriptions.
Server name and Resource groups are different for all subscriptions.
For example: Enterprise\dev Subscription.

```
Server              RESOURCE GROUP           SUBSCRIPTION
caddvsql11           DwDvRg01                Enterprise Dev/Test
caduasql11           DwUtRg01                Enterprise Dev/Test
cmspcsql01          CmsPcRg01                Enterprise Dev/Test
quomosql11          QuoMoRg11                Enterprise Dev/Test



Set-AzureRmContext  "Enterprise\dev " 

new-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName "DwDvRg01" -ServerName "caddvsql11" -FirewallRuleName "SAM_HOME" -StartIpAddress "22.7.180.91"
-EndIpAddress "22.7.180.91"
```

I am able to add ip address using this query for single server.But I need to add this firewall rule name and Ip address in all Paas servers in Azure, having different server and resource groups.
Can some one Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Set-AzureRmContext is the older version. There is a migration to the new Az cmdlets for [Cloud Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview).

If all resource groups are under the same Subscription ID, then the script you used could be extended to include a firewall rule on the remaining three servers.

If they are all on individual subscriptions, you will need to include the cmdlet ([Connect-AzAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/authenticate-azureps?view=azps-1.5.0)), followed by using the [Set-AzContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/set-azcontext) cmdlet to change between subscriptions.

If you connect via the Cloud Shell session via the Azure Portal, you can use Set-AzContext to switch between subscription. The Connect-AzAccount cmdlet is needed if you are running from a desktop environment and need to authenitcate first.

Comment: I have different Subscriptions like Enterprise dev\test, Prod, UAT .This was just example.I have multiple servers with different resource groups so I can't write this script multiple times.I am looking for script where I can either use parameters or save all servername and resource group in file and add IP Address accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple csv file with all the required inputs and then make use of [Import-csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6) command.

Here is a quick sample csv and script.. You can add any other columns you need and make use of the values in appropriate commands.

[image]

```
foreach($rule in import-csv "E:\firewallrules.csv") 
{ 
   Write-Host "Processing item with.. Server="$rule.Server "Resource Group ="$rule.ResourceGroup "Subscription="$rule.Subscription

   # Make use of variables like $rule.Server and so on in your commands here..
}
```